# firefoxのスタートページに表示されるスクリーンショットを指定できるか？

Tags: html, firefox

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

firefoxのスタートページに表示されるスクリーンショットをサーバー側から指定することはできますか？
適当なスクロール状態でキャプチャされた画像が表示されるのカッコ悪いので、いっその事こっち側（サイトを作ってる側）で画像を指定したいのですが、そんなこと可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

サムネイルに関してはFirefox側の処理で取得していると思いますので
サーバー側からは明示的に指定することは出来ないと思います。